# Uniqueness of factorization in the Selberg class

Tags: nt.number-theory

Hello,

typing "Selberg class" on Google, I got to read this: http://www.aimath.org/WWN/rh/articles/html/11a/
Frankly, I'm quite surprised, since I thought uniqueness of factorization hadn't been proven yet. So, what's the truth about this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The person who typed it probably wasn't being careful. I wouldn't read anything into it.

Comment: Selberg's conjectures imply the uniqueness of factorization. http://www.aimath.org/WWN/rh/articles/html/82a/

Comment: Ok, thanks. By the way, has some progress been made towards establishing the general converse conjecture (namely that every element of the Selberg class is an automorphic L-function, for which uniqueness of factorization has been proven)?

Comment: I haven't heard anything about it!